# React Custom Hook with Typescript Type error "Property 'x' does not exist on type 'interface | (({ target }: any) => void)'.ts(2339)"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to manage a form using a custom hook, so i have this code

**FormHook.tsx:**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

interface ICampos  {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}


const useForm = (initialState: ICampos) => {
    
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);


    const handleInputChange = ({ target }: any) => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [target.name]: target.value
        })
    };

    return [values, handleInputChange];
}

export default useForm
```

**FormWithCustomHook.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react'
import './effects.css' 
import useForm from '../../hooks/useForm';

interface ICampos  {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const FormWithCustomHook = () => {

    const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const { name, email, password } = formValues;



    return (
        <>
            <h1> FormWithCustomHook </h1>
            <hr />

            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Tu nombre"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
            </div>
            
            <div className="form-group">

                <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="email@ejemplo.com"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">

                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="*****"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default FormWithCustomHook;
```

And I'm stuck with this error on line of FormWithCustomHook.tsx:

```
const { name, email, password } = formValues;
```

It only marks the error only on email and password:

'Property 'email' does not exist on type 'ICampos | (({ target }: any) => void)'.ts(2339)'

And in my onChange inside of the inputs says:

Type 'ICampos | (({ target }: any) => void)' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent) => void) | undefined'.
Type 'ICampos' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent) => void'.
Type 'ICampos' provides no match for the signature '(event: ChangeEvent): void'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2092, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes, HTMLInputElement>''

I'd tryed to add types on the customhook.tsx but I really don't understand this error

Comment: I've updated my answer, showing one solution typing the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hook doesn't know the order of the array. So it might be `ICampos | Handler` or `Handler | ICampos`. You have two options here:

You can type the return array on the hook:

```
const useForm = (
  initialState: ICampos
): [ICampos, ({ target }: any) => void] => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<ICampos>(initialState);

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: any) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  };

  return [values, handleInputChange];
};
```

Or you could return an object instead of an array. I prefer this one since I don't like typing arrays.

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface ICampos {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const useForm = (initialState: ICampos) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<ICampos>(initialState);

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: any) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  };

  return { values, handleInputChange };
};

export default useForm;
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./effects.css";
import useForm from "./useForm";

interface ICampos {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const FormWithCustomHook = () => {
  const { values, handleInputChange } = useForm({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const { name, email, password } = values;

  return (
    <>
      <h1> FormWithCustomHook </h1>
      <hr />

      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Tu nombre"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={name}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="email@ejemplo.com"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="*****"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={password}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormWithCustomHook;
```

Comment: Yep this was my first way to do it, however if you return an object it makes you use the name of the object variable when it was exported and if you return an array you can rename the functions and objects as you like in the component, this makes them more modular :(

Comment: You could always use an alias when destructuring the object. If you want to use an array, you will need to type it, as shown above

Comment: Ups, thankyou! this was exactly what I was looking for, sorry, didn't see your edit.